# iOS / Master Detail : how to pop the subdetail view when switching detail from the master controller?

Tags: ios, master-detail, uisplitview

I am still working on my iPad RSS Reader.
It consists of 2 Views:

- the Master view, where one can choose the Feed
- The Detail View where all the posts of a given Feed appear

Whenever touching a Post Cell, I follow a segue which pushes a WebView on top of my Detail controller.

If I select another Feed in the Master View when I have such a Webview over my Detail View, it will load it, but *below* the displayed WebView.

How may I "empty" the Detail View (=pop its eventually pushed Web View) whenever switching Feeds?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using the `replace` segue. It was designed for that specific purpose.

Comment: Have you tried using the replace segue? Which segue are you currently using? How are you performing your segue? How is your segue created?

Comment: Hello, **Thanks** for your answer. My segue was defined as push, I replaced with popover but now I cannot get back if I click the WebView. Also, selecting another feed doesn't replace the WebView with another Feed list...

Comment: Don't use the popover segue. Use the `replace` segue. I don't mean "replace the segue" I mean use the `replace` segue. The name of the segue that you want to use is called `replace`.

Comment: You mean that one, don't you? http://i.imgur.com/ZVa2AEv.jpg Well it's the one I'm using but it does not work for me. Also, I'm missing the top navigation bar in the detail View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I added the following in the Master Controller `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
        [self.detailViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And it works expectedly with a push segue.